# udev rules with a math expression

Tags: serial-port, udev

I have a udev rule that creates a symlink for serial devices (USB serial ports) using an expression like this: `SYMLINK+="MyDevice_%n"`. The %n assigns the system device node number starting with 0. Is there a way to modify the numbering - instead of %n, perhaps %n+1? Math expressions don't work in a udev rule. I might be able to use a bash script to do the equivalent of `echo $((%n+1))` but I'm not sure how to do this in a udev rule. Any helpful suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the udev rules PROGRAM field to execute a /bin/sh echo expression and capture the result using %c, like this...

```
PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'echo $((%n+1))'", SYMLINK+="MyDevice_%c"
```

The resulting symlink will have the equivalent of `MyDevice_$((%n+1))` or `MyDevice_1` if %n is zero. The $(()) construct is called "arithmetic expansion" and causes the contents to be evaluated as an integer expression. It's a syntax element of the shell.

Comment: In newer udev versions, you need to escape the `$` as `$$`. 

Not sure when this changed.  

See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html#%24%24

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to start from `MyDevice_0`, use `++%n` to start the counter from 1 (`MyDevice_1`)

`PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'echo $((++%n))'", SYMLINK+="MyDevice_%c"`

Comment: Maybe you mean "to start the counter from 1"? Starting at 0 is exactly what OP doesn't want :)

Comment: Oops, I misread the OP. Sorry. Yeah, there is no need to use `PROGRAM` at all to start with 0 since you can simply use `%n`